# Cross Compile C++ program from Windows to Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile a simple program made in C++ from windows to my raspberry pi 4 B.
For that I use Cmake but I don't know what to use to compile the program. Visual Studio it seems can compile Arm and Arm64 but according to the documentation, the Rp4 is in ArmV8 and when I do `uname -m` on the Rp4 I get `armv71`. I don't know what to indicate in CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /home/devel/rasp-pi-rootfs)
set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX /home/devel/stage)

set(tools /home/devel/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

project(SCWWS CXX)

#=================== INCLUSION OF Project Files ====================#
set(FORMS_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/forms")
set(INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
set(SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

include_directories(${FORMS_DIR})
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${SOURCE_DIR})

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES
    "${INCLUDE_DIR}/*.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp"
)

#=================== SETUP EXECTUABLE ====================#

# Add the executable
add_executable(SCWWS ${SOURCES})

# Add the target includes for SCWWS 
target_include_directories(SCWWS PRIVATE ${FORMS_DIR})
target_include_directories(SCWWS PRIVATE ${INCLUDE_DIR})
target_include_directories(SCWWS PRIVATE ${SOURCE_DIR})
```

When I run my program on the Rp4 I get this error:

`-bash: ./SCWWS: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

For now, here is the cpp code that I am compiling:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Hello World !";
    return 0;
}
```

For later, I would like to make a Qt application, will there be anything else to do?

Comment: The lines you put between `cmake_minimum_required` and `project` calls should be moved into the **toolchain file**, which is specified with `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=...` option to `cmake`. As far as I understand, Visual Studio generators doesn't support toolchain files. For configure the project for ARM on Visual Studio, use `-A` option to `cmake`, as described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html).

Comment: For an Rp4, should I use Arm or Arm64 ?

Comment: Also, it seems that Visual Studio only build exe programs, what could I use to compile for linux ?

Comment: @LolixDudu Its a bit confusing: The Rp4 has a 64 Bit ArmV8 CPU, but the default version of Raspbian that is installed is 32 bits only, so it actually runs in ArmV7 mode. Unless you have the Beta 64-Bit Raspbian installed, you need to build for Arm.

Comment: **Just Don't!** I tried something like that, but it was really complicated and a mess. Simple solution: **1. First,** Connect your Pi4 to a display for single time and enable VNC in configs. **2. Then,** connect the Pi4 to your computer's WiFi hotspot (then it will connect automatically in future). **3. Finally, Download, install and use free `VNC` client on your computer** to connect to your Pi4 (simply type `arp -a` to find your RasperyPi's IP address, in local-net).